# Why behat fails to run in windows 7?

Tags: php, windows, behat

I have installed behat in C:\Behat on a windows7 system. I have added the path C:\Behat\bin to the environment variable 'Path' ....but when I run php bin\behat or php behat I just get an error message 'Could not open input file'
However when I run php "C:\Behat\bin\behat" , it works!
Can anyone tell me how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: So that means it's correctly running?

Comment: I read somewhere that we should be able to run behat by just typing behat or bin\behat :S

Comment: Is there a BEHAT.EXE in C:\Behat\bin?  If there is, just don't put the `php` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

To run `php bin\behat` you would have to already be in the `C:\Behat` folder.  To run `php behat` you would have to already be in the `C:\Behat\bin` folder.

Your search path is only good for the php executable, not its parameter list.